# How to install MySQL 5.6.23 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, installation

I am trying to install MySQL 5.6.23, but it seems it is not an easy path.

I had Mysql 5.5 on Ubuntu 14.04 in a VM.

I ran, `sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6`. Mysql 5.6.19 got installed, but how do I update it to 5.6.23?

The Mysql site also does not provide the download link!

Comment: Here an answer for this... http://askubuntu.com/questions/203330/how-to-install-mysql-5-6

Comment: Instead asking here, google it ...

Comment: i have been googleing it for passed couple of hours!! Didn't you have any better answer ??

Comment: @tanaydin, Thanks for your reply, but that link didn't helped

Comment: Uninstall existing MySQL, download tar.gz file, unpack in /opts, symbolic link to mysql data, start mysqld. Should do it.

Comment: You should do a google search: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/upgrade-mysql-5-5-to-5-6-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 1):

Add a repo

```
echo "deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ precise mysql-apt-config
deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ precise mysql-5.6" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list

curl -s http://ronaldbradford.com/mysql/mysql.gpg | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get other versions apart from the current recommended ones from the archive:

http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/

They're tar archives though so will need more active management and configuration than .deb files.  But at least you *can* run specific older versions.

It's been a while since I ran a version from there and I don't remember if source is included.  If it is, you might be able to use the source and a src deb (replace the source from the src deb) and build a deb for yourself.

Comment: apologies.  there *are* packages for different platforms.  I didn't click on the "Select Platform" so missed them :-).

Good luck.

Answer (score -3):

To install MySQL, open terminal and type in these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql
```

During the installation, MySQL will ask you to set a root password. If you miss the chance to set the password while the program is installing, it is very easy to set the password later from within the MySQL shell.

Once you have installed MySQL, we should activate it with this command:

```
sudo mysql_install_db
```

Finish up by running the MySQL set up script:

```
sudo /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

The prompt will ask you for your current root password.

Type it in.

Enter current password for root (enter for none):

OK, successfully used password, moving on...

Then the prompt will ask you if you want to change the root password. Go ahead and choose N and move on to the next steps.
It’s easiest just to say Yes to all the options. At the end, MySQL will reload and implement the new changes.

By default, a MySQL installation has an anonymous user, allowing anyone
to log into MySQL without having to have a user account created for
them.  This is intended only for testing, and to make the installation
go a bit smoother.  You should remove them before moving into a
production environment.

Remove anonymous users? [Y/n] y
 ... Success!

Normally, root should only be allowed to connect from 'localhost'.  This
ensures that someone cannot guess at the root password from the network.

Disallow root login remotely? [Y/n] y
... Success!

By default, MySQL comes with a database named 'test' that anyone can
access.  This is also intended only for testing, and should be removed
before moving into a production environment.

Remove test database and access to it? [Y/n] y
 - Dropping test database...
 ... Success!
 - Removing privileges on test database...
 ... Success!

Reloading the privilege tables will ensure that all changes made so far
will take effect immediately.

Reload privilege tables now? [Y/n] y
 ... Success!

Cleaning up...

Comment: Thanks Iman for your response.
The  answer to my question is  , for installing Mysql 6.5.20 and later you need Ubuntu 15.04.